How to add multiple user certificates for same site in AutoSelectCertificateForUrls regkey
I have multiple users and their certificates for authentication. I need to select the certificate manually when I log in to Chrome. I want to automate this scenario. I found a solution using regkey, which worked for me mentioned below.
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\AutoSelectCertificateForUrls" /v "1" /d "{'pattern': 'https://example.com', 'filter': {'SUBJECT': {'CN': 'subject Name'}}}"

But above scenario worked only if I have single user to login. If I try to login with another user with different certificate, I get certification Error unless I delete above regkey.
I found we can add multiple values for different user certificates as shown below:
[...] an array of stringified JSON dictionaries, each with the form { "pattern": "$URL_PATTERN", "filter" : $FILTER }, where $URL_PATTERN is a content setting pattern.
['{"pattern":"https://example.com","filter":{"SUBJECT":{"CN":"user cert 1 name"}}}',
 '{"pattern":"https://certauth.login.microsoftonline.com","filter":{"SUBJECT":{"CN":"user cert 2 name}}}']

But After adding the above data for regkey AutoSelectCertificateForUrls, Nothing works, I start getting certificate pop up again. (Even single user certificate also stops working)
Can somebody please assist how can I provide multiple data for different user certificate for AutoSelectCertificateForUrls regkey ?
